# embed non web application in jetty

Tags: jetty

How can I configure jetty6 to start a non web application (not a servlet)? My Java app is a rabbitmq consumer listening for ampq messages over tcp. I could have jetty init() call my Main entry point. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not provide a trivial servlet that provides an `init()` method and invoke your application from within there ? i.e. wrap it within a servlet wrapper that does next to nothing.

It doesn't *have* to respond to `GETs`/`POSTs` etc. Although you'd probably find that useful and report application status via a simple HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide a little more info if you want a complete answer but there are a few approaches I could suggest, that will give different behaviours (you'll need to pick the right one for your use case)

**1.** Just put the right code in your `jetty.xml` file. The XML file is a pretty complete execution language, so you can simply call methods on objects. An appropriate static method, along with a `<call>` tag should do the trick
The downside, is that you're not really getting any thing from Jetty - you just tying your startup method into the same startup process that Jetty uses.

**2.** Build a component that implements the Jetty `LifeCycle` interface (your best option is to extend `AbstractLifeCycle`), and then call `Server.addLifeCycle()`
That will allow you to open your port when Jetty starts up, shutdown cleanly when Jetty, stops, etc.
But all you get is that lifecycle. You don't get anything around deployment.

**3.** Same as option 1, but put it in [`jetty-web.xml`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/jetty-web.xml)  (or `jetty-env.xml`), which allows you to tie it into the deployment of a WAR file.
It doesn't buy you much over option 1, but if you're trying to deploy an application to an existing Jetty setup, it might help.

**4.** Same as option 1, but using `jetty-web.xml`. I'm not sure how well that would work, since I don't think you can attach a `LifeCycle` to a `WebAppContext`, but it might work OK - you'd need to do more investigation on that.

**5.** As per [Brian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947702/embed-non-web-application-in-jetty/4947780#4947780), simply write a servlet with an `init()` method, and `initialise-on-startup`, then don't map it to any URLs. Put a call to your entry method inside that `init`.